# Remove space between Navigation Bar and the Carousel (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am trying to remove white space between Navigation bar and the carousel in Bootstrap. I've found a lots of answer but none worked for me. Please take a look at the my code if I am doing anything wrong.

jsp for carousel

```
<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" id="bs-carousel">
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
        <div class="slide-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
        <div class="slide-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
        <div class="slide-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css file

```
.fade-carousel {
position: relative;
height: 100vh;
padding-top: 0px;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
height: 100vh;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li.active {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
opacity: 1;
}
.navbar {
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* Responsiveness of the link bar */
@media ( min-width : 767px) {
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #4e0300;
}
.navbar-nav>li.dropdown.open>a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: Please add working code. Code provided does not result any problem

Comment: include the navigation bar as well - the carousel code may not be the source of the issue

Comment: I've edited my question and this is what I got for Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying negative padding/margin?

```css
padding: -5px;
```

Comment: Are you saying you have whitespace here? 
http://prntscr.com/e2e8gj

If so create new class.
.vertical {
margin-top: 0px !important;
}

And stick it in
<div class="vertical carousel fade-carousel slide"
Section

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle? jsfiddle.com